# Errors in cv2.drawContours openCV related to its argument

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to draw contours in mask image. While, I had an error following:
`TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'image'`

My codes are below and they were executed in OpenCV(4.5.1) and python(3.9.12)

```
cmask = np.array(deepcopy(mask), dtype="uint8")

mask_img = np.array(cmask.copy(), dtype="uint8")

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
Remove = np.zeros_like(cmask)
for n in contours:
   area = cv2.contourArea(n)
   print (area)
   print (n)
   if area < 100:
     cv2.drawContours(Remove, n, 0, (1), -1)
   cmask[Remove > 0] = 0
   return cmask
```

I found`cv2.drawContours` should have an argument of image from previous posts. However, I suspect my code should work without problem since "Remove" is 'Array of uint8', which is not different array 8 bit image read by "OpenCV".

At the same time when I define "Remove" as `Remove = np.zeros_like(cmask.copy(), dtype="uint8")`, I did not have any problem to run the program.

My questions are what is right way to define "Remove" without such an error?
Also, I am wondering the alternative code will work as I intended. If so, can you explain why I did not have an error in the alternative code?

Comment: In `cv2.drawContours(Remove, n, 0, (1), -1)`, why are you drawing (1) and not (255) if your Remove is uint8?  It won't be visible at (1). Try using [n] in `cv2.drawContours(Remove, [n], 0, (255), -1)`

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you for your advice and all makes sense now!